# Requesting Recording Label/Marketing Label

Tags: gracenote

I'm trying to get some data from the Music Web API to populate some data on my side so I can later in fill in some song play reports. In order to do this, I've got a requirement to retrieve the ISRC of tracks as well as the Recording Label or Marketing Label for their albums (for cases where an ISRC is not available).

However, I'm not seeing a way to retrieve recording label in the docs https://developer.gracenote.com/sites/default/files/web/webapi/index.html#music-overview/Album%20Data.html (or anywhere else in the docs).

I'm either blind or this data isn't available but it would be great to get confirmation either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label data is not available through WebAPI. You will need to use GNSDK to retrieve Label data instead.